# jquery get value of each button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the value of each button, but what i get is the value of the first button. This is my content

```
<div class="my_btn">
<button id="id_button" value="page-1">Page One</button>
<button id="id_button" value="page-2">Page Two</button>
<button id="id_button" value="page-3">Page Three</button>
<button id="id_button" value="page-4">Page Four</button>
</div>
```

and this is my script

```
jQuery('.my_btn').on('click',function(){
var my_content = jQuery('#id_button').val();
var my_link = '<li><a href="/'+my_content+'.php">Link</a></li>';

if( !tinyMCE.activeEditor || tinyMCE.activeEditor.isHidden()) {
jQuery('textarea#content').val(my_link);
} else {
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, my_link);
}
});
```

Basically this is a wordpress function. I'm trying to add different links inside the textarea box.

Thanks in advance

Comment: fairly simple...ID's are unique in a page by defintion. If there were 5 houses on your street all with the same address number..everyone's mail would likely all end up at the first one too

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same id, that's not valid html, jquery will use the native `getElementById` and return the value of the first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the event listener to the buttons instead of the wrapper, then get the value with `this.value`.

```js
jQuery('.my_btn button').on('click',function(){
    var my_content = this.value;
    var my_link = '<li><a href="/'+my_content+'.php">Link</a></li>';
    if( !tinyMCE.activeEditor || tinyMCE.activeEditor.isHidden()) {
        jQuery('textarea#content').val(my_link);
    } else {
       tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, my_link);
    }
});
```

Also, you should use unique values for each `id` attribute. While it won't effect *this* script, if you try to select by `id` then it will only affect the first element with that `id`.

```js
jQuery('.my_btn button').on('click',function(){
    var my_content = this.value;
    alert(my_content);
    /*var my_link = '<li><a href="/'+my_content+'.php">Link</a></li>';
    if( !tinyMCE.activeEditor || tinyMCE.activeEditor.isHidden()) {
        jQuery('textarea#content').val(my_link);
    } else {
       tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, my_link);
    }*/
});
```

```html
<div class="my_btn">
<button id="id_button_1" value="page-1">Page One</button>
<button id="id_button_2" value="page-2">Page Two</button>
<button id="id_button_3" value="page-3">Page Three</button>
<button id="id_button_4" value="page-4">Page Four</button>
</div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

first off id_button should be a class because it is on multiple elements 
second your first jquery command should look like this, this way it will handle the button click and get the correct value

```
jQuery('.my_btn').on('click', '.id_button',function(){
    var my_content = $(this).val();
    var my_link = '<li><a href="/'+my_content+'.php">Link</a></li>';

    if( !tinyMCE.activeEditor || tinyMCE.activeEditor.isHidden()) {
        jQuery('textarea#content').val(my_link);
    } else {
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, my_link);
    }
});
```